# How to limit latest block in Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, rinkeby

I need some test Ethereum blockchains for development purposes. I need only part of blocks synced for example, blochain synced from 0 to 10'000`th block, because for example Rinkeby synced in archive/full mode brings more than 100 GB, in fast more than 14 GB and this size is not practical.
Geth seems to do not sync in archive/full mode until get synced in fast mode to latest block.
Do anyone knows how to limit latest block in Geth?
Maybe you know some websites with small size presynced blockchains, it can be Ethereum, Rinkeby, other testnets, whatever, a small size blockchain synced in archive/full mode?

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to sync just a bit of a public chain is a strange way to achieve what you want.

I’d recommend creating your own private chain as outlined in [this blog post](https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/how-to-create-your-own-private-ethereum-blockchain-dad6af82fc9f).

You can mine an appropriate number of blocks containing appropriate transactions for your development needs and allow your developers to sync that chain.

Alternatively you could just run it on a separate server that your team can connect to and you would only need to maintain one node.

Comment: I dont need to make own changes to blockchain, just to scan it.

Comment: TL;DR You can’t ‘scan’ just a part of the public chain.

Comment: Also the very first blocks of mainnet, ropsten, rinkeby are uninteresting because they are empty or with few transactions.